# What's missing with my project.json building using nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

> ERROR in ./services/emailService.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/apis/adl/instance/EmailsApi' in

I'm getting this error when running the nuxt build inside docker container or in some CI/CD server like code build. this works properly in my local machine. I'm using mac. anyone can help?

Comment: what are you trying to build?. SPA, Universal or Static?. Please provide a bit of more background.

Comment: we are builing SPA using vuejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it work fine locally its most likely because of case sensitivity. CI/CD usually run on linux, and usual filesystem on linux is case dependent.

While MacOs usually run on case-insensitive file system. So your file is found on Mac, but not on linux because its in different case

Comment: thanks for your answer and yes it was a f case sensitive issue only.